# Is it possible to create a task with an attachment in Asana?

Tags: c#, asana-api

I am looking at the following references: https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks and https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments. Am I correct to assume that you cannot create a task with an attachment in it using the Asana's API? Or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create it.
You first need to Create a Task.
This will return a "taskid".

https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/attachments#upload

Then in the next request you need to add attachment to that task.